# IgnoreSSLError not working in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview

I am very new to ReactNative. I have developed a webview app for both android and ios. The Url for UAT server doesnt have certificate, this causes the webview not load. I tried in Android Studio, with the method **ONRECEIVEDSSLERROR()** i was able to ignore SSL issue but not able to do in react native pls help. I have attached code snippet below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default function App({ navigation }) {
  return (
        <WebView
          source= {{ uri: 'myurl' }}
          ignoreSslError={true}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
        />
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For development you may just try to subdue this error directly in `react-native-webview` source code. For that go to `node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewManager.java` and change `handler.cancel()` to `handler.proceed()` in `onReceivedSslError` method.

Somehow it doesn't always work. For me this method didn't solve problem when I was trying to use `npx create-expo-app` but it helped me when I created and executed app by react-native cli tool.